# Fastest Checkmates

Tags: chess

I'm not very good at all at chess, but was thinking about some interesting chess variations and thought of this question.

It is well known that the fastest (i.e. fewest moves required) checkmate is the [Fool's Mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate). My question is, what are the corresponding fastest checkmates when the kings are given the moveset of each of the other pieces (one at a time)? As a trivial example, if the kings' movement rules are replaced with those of a pawn, the answer is the same (fool's mate still applies). The fastest I have been able to come up with are:

> Pawn, Rook, Knight: 2
>   Bishop, Queen: 3

The green check goes to the first person who can match my records (with steps listed). I will award a 50 reputation bounty to anyone who can beat my record for bishop/queen (I doubt it is possible though). As in the case of Fool's Mate, you are allowed to make one player play atrociously; this is a proof of concept, not a realistic line of play. Good luck!

Comment: How do you count moves? Each player is 0.5 moves?

Comment: I believe it's only counting your moves, the opponent doesn't count.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Count the number of moves made by the person who wins (including the winning move). To my knowledge, since your opponent can never put themselves in checkmate with a move, it will always be the winning players move last. i.e. this will always result in the same answer as the method you suggested, but is simpler to count

Comment: It's not quite the same, but let's go with your counting. (If white wins on his second move, that's 1.5 moves; whereas it would be 2 moves if black wins.)

Comment: There's a 4 mover that involves moving out your king's pawn, then your bishop and then your queen, and finally rushing your queen into your opponents front line while covered by your bishop. it only works on people who don't know about it or have the dumb luck to break the maneuver accidentally. I don't know what software to use to show that so i'll leave my answer here. Just play with the board and those pieces and you'll find it. This move is about pure murder and not relying on you opponent's clumsiness.

Comment: @moonbutt74 You probably mean this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar%27s_mate

Comment: @Sleafar yup that's the one, my brother used to get me with that one all the time. I punched him in the face once for doing it. xD

Comment: there's an even quicker mate, but it does require white to play particularly badly...  f3? e6. g4?? Qh4#

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pawn + Rook:

> This is basically the Fool's Mate again.
>  [image]

Knight:

> I had to replace the King with a Knight for this.
>  [image]

Bishop + Queen:

> This actually works for all pieces except the Knight. In normal chess games something like this is called ["smothered mate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smothered_mate).
>  [image]

Another variant for the Bishop (there are even more):

> [image]

Comment: Nicely done! I bestow upon ye, the green check!

Comment: Funnily, your "variant" for the Bishop doesn't work if the Black king is also changed into a Bishop-moving piece.